# How do I use contraction in sentences like 'My brother and I have got a lot of toys'?

Tags: contractions

My question is as follows: is it grammatically correct - I would like to be referred to reliable sources - to contract such like subjects and the main or auxiliary *have*:

> My brother and I *have* got a lot of toys.
>
> My Mum and I *have* been to Greece twice.

Is there any rule that advises us to contract or not contract in the above instances?

And is there any rule of thumb at all that helps us to use contraction properly with proper names? E.g.:

> Peter and Pavel *have* graduated from university.

Comment: Have a look at this: [Contraction Grammar Chant](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarchants/fl/Contraction-Grammar-Chant.htm), and scroll down to *Note on the verb "Have"*: 'Contractions are used with the verb "have" only when the verb "have" takes the role of the helping verb. However, when "have" is used as the main verb, it is not contracted.' The link contains very helpful examples. I'd post this as an answer, except that my answer would simply consist of a copy of the section I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience (in American English), in *writing*, while singular verbs can always be contracted, plural verbs are generally only contracted when the subject is a pronoun.

> They've got a lot of toys
>
> We've been to Greece twice

When the subject is *A and B*, I've not seen contractions used very often, even in informal writing.  That's not to say it's *wrong*, just that it's not common.

In *speech*, however, a contraction would be common, so that when pronounced, it would sound like

> Peter and Pavel've graduated from university

It would only be written this way if you were specifically trying to mimic spoken English, in which case it could be considered [eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect).